# Enforce HH24:MM in input type=time?

Tags: html, html-input

I want to use HTML5's `<input type="time">`-field. It allows to support the user entering a time formatted string (like HH:MM). I want that users enter the time in format `HH24:MM` and with no (micro)seconds.

[But the working draft](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.time.html) does not specify how to do that and what the current standard for the format is.

How can I ensure users use only `HH24:MM`-times without using two select lists (one for hour and one for minute)?